# How to interact with database by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, database, autocomplete

I have an annoying problem. I use the **autocomplete** extender provided by ASP.NET in my Web Forms application written in C#. The autocomplete works good, no problem.

I use the autocomplete with the serial_number textfield. If I want to fill in the product_name textfield based on what serial_number I have chosen I need to interact with the database. 
That is because the **Web Method** that provides data to the autocomplete must have a specific signature and its output parameters is an **array of strings**.

Therefore once the serial_number is selected, I need to call a jQuery function that given the selected **serial_number** gets the corresponging **product_name** from the database (SQL Server).

Any suggestion? Thanks

UPDATE:

The Web Method feeding the autocomplete

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string[] GetProductId(string prefixText, int count)
{
    string selectSQL = "SELECT srnum FROM demo_product WHERE srnum LIKE'" +  prefixText + "' + '%'";
    DataTable dtProdId = dbUtil.dbGetDataTable("EMPLOYEE", selectSQL);

    List<string> listProdId = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dtProdId.Rows)
    {
        listProdId.Add((string)row["SRNUM"]);
    }

    return listProdId.ToArray();
}
```

And the markup in aspx file

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSRNum" BackColor="#FFFF66" AutoComplete="On"></asp:TextBox>

 <!-- Autocomplete extender for product serial number -->
 <ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtSRNum_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server"
 DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True" ServicePath="" TargetControlID="txtSRNum"
 MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetProductId" CompletionSetCount="5"
 CompletionInterval="50" >

    </ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Depending on your server-side configuration, your jQuery could look as simple as this:

```
$.getJSON('/Products.aspx/LookupSerialNumber',
  {serial_number: $('#serial_number').val()},
  function(json) {
    $('#product_name').val(json.product.product_name);
  }
);
```

It's hard to give a more concrete example without knowing specifics.

Comment: thanks! I updated the question maybe it gives you a wider context. I also do not understand what LookupSerialNumber is